# How to call a stored procedure of oracle in struts2

Tags: jdbc, oracle10g

I want to call a stored procedure name (mytable1) of oracle 10g in the below code of struts.  How to do that ?

```
    import java.sql.*;
    public class loginuser 
    {
    public String username;
    public String password;
    public String execute()
    {       

    Connection con;
    Statement stmt;
    ResultSet rs;
    try
    {

    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","Gaurav","oracle");
    stmt=con.createStatement();
    rs=stmt.executeQuery(" HOW TO CALL A PROCEDURE");

    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
    {

    }
    catch(SQLException ex)
    {
    }
    }
    public String getpassword()
    {
            return password;
        }
       public void setpassword(String m)
    {
            this.password = m;
    }

    public String getusername() {
    return username;
    }

    public void setusername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
    }
    }
```

Below is the procedure :

```
CREATE  or replace PROCEDURE mytable1 (tname varchar2)
is
stmt varchar2(1000);
begin
stmt := 'CREATE TABLE '||tname || '(username varchar2(20) ,password varchar2 (10))';
execute immediate stmt;
end;
```

Comment: This is not a struts 2 question. It's a jdbc question.  Know what I mean?

Comment: oh.. my mistake.. you are right(actually i was making a struts2 program using this JDBC code). so can you please tel me how to call that procedure ?

Comment: See the [JDBC Tutorial on Stored Procedures](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/storedprocedures.html) and the Oracle JDBC Developer Guide: [Stored Procedure Calls in JDBC Programs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/getsta.htm#JJDBC28075)