# How to call a stored procedure of oracle through jdbc code

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I want to call a stored procedure name (mytable1) of oracle 10g through JDBC. 
could you please tell me how to do that ? (I am using this code in a struts2 programme)

```
import java.sql.*;
public class loginuser 
{
public String username;
public String password;
public String execute()
{       

Connection con;
Statement stmt;
ResultSet rs;
try

import java.sql.*;
public class loginuser 
{
public String username;
public String password;
public String execute()
{       

Connection con;
Statement stmt;
ResultSet rs;
try
{

Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","Gaurav","oracle");
stmt=con.createStatement();
rs=stmt.executeQuery(" HOW TO CALL A PROCEDURE ? ");

}
catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
{

}
catch(SQLException ex)
{
}
}
public String getpassword()
{
        return password;
    }
   public void setpassword(String m)
{
        this.password = m;
}

public String getusername() {
return username;
}

public void setusername(String username) {
this.username = username;
}
}
```

--Below is the procedure i want to call------------------

```
CREATE  or replace PROCEDURE mytable1 (tname varchar2)
is
stmt varchar2(1000);
begin
stmt := 'CREATE TABLE '||tname || '(username varchar2(20) ,password varchar2 (10))';
execute immediate stmt;
end;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call a stored procedure of oracle in struts2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17599487/how-to-call-a-stored-procedure-of-oracle-in-struts2)

Comment: Instead of posting an almost identical duplicate of your earlier question, consider editing/updating the original.

Answer (score 0):

Crummy way: (You can use your existing stmt and rs variables for this)

```
String query = "begin mytable1(?, ?); end;";
rs=stmt.executeQuery(query);
```

Good way:

```
//mytable1 is a stored procedure
String mytable1Sql = "{call mytable1(?)}";
CallableStatement callableStatement = dbConnection.prepareCall(mytable1Sql);
callableStatement.setString(1, "whatever");
// no out parameters, but i'll leave this in so you can see it.
// callableStatement.registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);

// execute mytable1 stored procedure
callableStatement.executeUpdate();

// no out parameters, but i'll leave this in so you can see it.
// String userName = callableStatement.getString(2);
```

This being said, I generally don't recommend creating tables with stored procedures.